# Passing response data into headers and other fields in subsequent requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, bluebird

I'm using the `Bluebird` promises library in conjunction with `request-promise`. This is my code:

```
var Bluebird = require('bluebird');
var rp = require('request-promise');

var request1 = rp(paramsReq1);
var request2 = rp(paramsReq2);
var request3 = rp(paramsReq3);

Bluebird.all([request1, request2, request3])
    .spread(function (responseOfReq1, responseOfReq2, responseOfReq3) {
        // All requests succeeded.
        // Process the responses now.
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // At least one request failed.
        // Do your error handling here.
    });
```

This works, however I need to pass some content returned from the first request (apikey) into a header in the second request. Then I need to pass some response data from the second request into the third request.

How can I best achieve this.

Comment: Did [my post below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627159/passing-response-data-into-headers-and-other-fields-in-subsequent-requests/39627301#39627301) answer your question? If it did then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) because right now other people searching for this problem see that your question has no good answer and may not read it. If it didn't answer your question then please comment on what is missing. I'm going through my old answers and I want to make sure they are good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use data from response 1 in request 2 and data from response 2 in request 3, then you can't run them all in parallel.

You have to do something like this:

```
rp(paramsReq1).then(function (responseOfReq1) {
  // do something with responseOfReq1 ...
  return rp(paramsReq2);
}).then(function (responseOfReq2) {
  // do something with responseOfReq2 ...
  return rp(paramsReq3);
}).then(function (responseOfReq3) {
  // do something with responseOfReq3 ...
}).catch(function (err) {
  // At least one request failed.
  // Do your error handling here.
});
```

In other words you have to chain the calls because if you need `responseOfReq1` to prepare `paramsReq2` then you can't call `rp(paramsReq2)` before the promise returned by `rp(paramsReq1)` gets resolved.

Running:

```
var request1 = rp(paramsReq1);
var request2 = rp(paramsReq2);
var request3 = rp(paramsReq3);
```

would not do what you need, because it would run them in parallel and the next requests wouldn't have access to the previous response - they would all get started at the same time before any of them gets any chance to finish. No matter what you do with the returned promises, the requests would already be started.

Comment: Actually I need to run them in serial. i.e. chain them togethr

Comment: @user1513388 Yes, and that's what I explained. Does it work for you?